# Use vue.js vue-notus template in laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, layout, vue-component, integrate

I have an *issue* integrating the `Vue.js` template( [Vue-Notus package here](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vue-notus)) into the empty [Laravel](https://laravel.com) project. How can I properly **copy+paste** from the template files into `Laravel`?

Comment: What do template looks like there?

Comment: I don't know how to integrate property. I have don't start yet. (